# How to deal with variations in web pages while web scrapping using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

So, I was scrapping a website for an MRP Attribute. Now, I did something like this:

```
try:
    MRP = soup.find('div', class_ = 'X')
except AttributeError:
    MRP = ""
```

Now, the issue is the website doesn't have a consistent format throughout. Some pages have this price information somewhat differently like some don't have div class = 'X' at all. To deal with this, I put another `try-except` inside the first `try-except` block `except` part. It is working fine. But is there a better way to deal with this? I am not even sure if this is efficient.

I have only seen 2-3 variations of the page; there might be more. This will make the task difficult.

But, the consistent thing is the page displays `MRP: 100` across all its variants. So, is there a way to do it by considering this info so it won't break?

Edit:
What I wanted to say was websites has something like this, I want to extract the number beside MRP. Now, the thing is there are some variations as below. So, using soup's find method with hard corded class is causing the problems. So, I tried to incorporate the different variations with something like this:

```
def get_MRP(soup):
    try:
        MRP = soup.find("span", attrs={"class":'a-price a-text-price a-size-base'}).span.text
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            MRP = soup.find("span", attrs={"class":'a-price a-text-price'}).span.text
        except AttributeError:
            MRP = ""
    return MRP
```

All I am asking if there is a better method to deal with this. As, this is a little bit hardcorded.

[image: MRP Variation 1]
[image: MRP Variation]

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @baduker Does my added edit help in any way? Sorry, for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [using selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors-through-the-css-property), particularly pseudo classes like [`:is`](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/#:is) or [`:where`](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/#:where), followed by if-else:

```py
MRP = soup.select_one('span:is(.a-price.a-text-price.a-size-base, .a-price.a-text-price) span')
MRP = MRP.text if MRP else ''
```

---

Although, you could just search only for the shared classes:

```py
MRP = soup.select_one('span.a-price.a-text-price span')
MRP = MRP.text if MRP else ''
```